# iPhone encrypt function that would be decrypt on php server

Tags: iphone, encryption

I want to write encrypt function in iPhone application that would be decrypt on server in php,

Decrypt function in php is this

```
function decrypt($input_text)
{
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $enc_key = "0e9d083f3514a69243bb8f1395d332c1";
    $out = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $enc_key, $input_text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $out;

}
```

I'm using following encryption code in iPhone

```
+(NSString*) encrypt:(NSString*) str key:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *key =key;
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

        // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    char *dataIn = [str UTF8String];
    char dataOut[500];// set it acc ur data
    bzero(dataOut, sizeof(dataOut));
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding|kCCOptionECBMode,  keyPtr,kCCKeySizeAES128, NULL, dataIn, strlen(dataIn), dataOut, sizeof(dataOut), &numBytesEncrypted);

    NSString* strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:dataOut] autorelease];
    return [strResult copy];
}
```

but didn't get the original result.
Please anybody can correct me where i'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- As said, use the same key length in both cases.
- In the CCCrypt call you don't store the iv that was generated, instead you pass NULL. You should store this and somehow transport it along the message to your PHP code. There, instead of generating a new, random iv you would *reuse* the existing one generated by the iPhone.
- On top of that, `mcrypt` does not support PKCS7Padding (also often referred to as PKCS5Padding), so unfortunately you need to [implement](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php#69782) it yourself. In your case, you first decrypt the iPhone's input and then apply the `pkcs5_unpad` function described in that article afterwards.

Comment: Awesome comment, you should have posted an answer for that!

Answer (score 0):

You are using AES with 256-bit key in the decryption and with 128-bit key in the encryption.  These are entirely different algorithms.